# jQuery(...).kendoChart is not a function error

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

i am using kendo chart in mvc razor

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart().Name("chart"))
```

using this js and cs files

```
<link href="~/Scripts/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Scripts/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: kendo Chart not showing when  i checked in browser console then error  occured jQuery(…).kendoChart is not a function may be  i missed some necessary file ?

Comment: It might be because you're installing JQuery twice (`jquery-1.9.1.min.js` and `jquery.min.js`)

Answer (score 6):

You are facing a problem because you are adding jquery twice in your code. Try removing `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` and
your code should work fine.